# pandas splitting a string in columns into multiple records

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as `df`

```
col1   col2  col3
a;b;c  w;x     1
d;e;f  x;y     2
g;h;i  z;u;v   3
```

I want to split each of the string in columns `col1` and `col2` into separate records, so that the dataframe looks something like this

```
col1    col2    col3
a       w       1
b       x       1
c       NaN     1
d       x       2
e       y       2
f       NaN     2
g       z       3
h       u       3
i       v       3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a combination of [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`Series.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`Series.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html), [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) like this:

#### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'col1': 'a;b;c', 'col2': 'w;x', 'col3': 1}, {'col1': 'd;e;f', 'col2': 'x;y', 'col3': 2}, {'col1': 'g;h;i', 'col2': 'z;u;v', 'col3': 3}, {'col1': '1,2,3', 'col2': '2', 'col3': 4}])

print(df)

#     col1   col2  col3
# 0  a;b;c    w;x     1
# 1  d;e;f    x;y     2
# 2  g;h;i  z;u;v     3
# 3  1,2,3      2     4

df_new = (pd.concat([df[x].str.split('[;,]', expand=True).stack().rename(x)
                     for x in df[['col1', 'col2']]], axis=1)
          .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
          .assign(col3=df.col3))

print(df_new)

  col1 col2  col3
0    a    w     1
0    b    x     1
0    c  NaN     1
1    d    x     2
1    e    y     2
1    f  NaN     2
2    g    z     3
2    h    u     3
2    i    v     3
3    1    2     4
3    2  NaN     4
3    3  NaN     4
```

Comment: I just ran the code and the above code doesn't really split the last row of df.

Comment: @AmanSingh hmm, the output i've printed is the output I got from running the above. Can you explain a bit further what hasn't worked right?

Comment: Based on you getting a value error on my answer, and this- are you sure that col1 and col2 are string type only?

Comment: @Chris A for the last three records I'm getting
`2    g  z;u;v     3\n2    h    NaN     3\n2    i    NaN     3 `

Comment: yes @ParmandeepChaddha everything in `col1` and `col2` is string type

Comment: your delimiters here in the comments are comma (`,`) but in your example data its semi-colon (`;`) ... The code above is splitting strings on ';'

Comment: @ChrisA appologies it was a typo

Comment: @AmanSingh I've updated my answer and added an additional row to the test data if you want to try again?

Comment: @ChrisA thanks, must have been something wrong at my end. I re-tried and it worked. thanks again